# find non repating elements in duplicate array

Tags: algorithms

i have an array which all his numbers is shows twice execpt for 3 numbers .
For one number i know - to do XOR with all numbers.
but for 3 i tried to play with the algoritm for one number - but couldnt find.
should be in running time O(n) without hashing . hint : its should be with XOR and with change to bitwise and do modolu.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to save? running time or space?

If you are space bounded, do the following:

> 0)Let $count=3$ 1)Fix an index i. Run on the array and try to find the
>   same number.
>
> 2)If succeed, $count=-1$
>
> 3)If not, continue to the next index.

If you are time bounded, do the following:

> 0)Create a hashmap. Keys are the numbers and the values are counters.
>
> 1)Run on the array and try inserting the numbers to the hashmap.
>
> 2)In the end, return the numbers with counter equal to 1.